# How can I reduce count of using useState for modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about using many states in one useState. I have two buttons (will about 10) and after click on button, it shows some information typical only for one button (choice). So state must be individual for every button. Is there any way to reduce to one useState for all buttons?
Now I have:

```
  const [showConfirmModalGoals, setShowConfirmModalGoals] = useState(false);
  const [showConfirmModalBallPos, setShowConfirmModalBallPos] = useState(false);
  
  const showModalForGoals = () => {
    setShowConfirmModalGoals(true);
  };
  

  const hideModalForGoals = () => {
    setShowConfirmModalGoals(false);
  };

  const showModalForBallPos = () => {
    setShowConfirmModalBallPos(true);
  };
  

  const hideModalForBallPos = () => {
    setShowConfirmModalBallPos(false);
  };

return(
<Modal show={showConfirmModalGoals} ... > GOALS </Modal>
<Button onClick={showModalForGoals} />

<Modal show={showConfirmModalBallPos} ... > Ball position</Modal>
<Button onClick={showModalForBallPos} />
);
```

So If I will 10 buttons with different content, I need 10 different states for these buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! You just need one modal for all buttons.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
```

Then, for every button:

```
<Button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} />
```

And then you will change the Modal's content (header, body & footer) dependent on the clicked button.

Comment: I would recommend doing it this way.  No more than one modal should ever be in use at a time, and after several years of utilizing multiple modals I want to attempt to refactor our applications to only use a single one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am confused, how can I change content in modal by only clicking on button. Can you explain this deeper?

Comment: There is some solutions to handel it... for example, you can add state, like modalState: {modalHeader: {....}, modalBody: {...}, modalFooter: {...}, modalIsOpen: false}, and when you click on a button you change all those states and you put the modalIsOpen to true ! ... Pay attention that if you do it like this, you will no more have need to the showModal state (beacause of the modalIsOpen...)

Comment: I created for store state:

    const [stateModal, setStateModal] = useState({
      modalHeader: ''",
      modalBody: null,
      modalStatus: false
    });

Showmodal :

 const showModal = (header, body) => {
      setStateModal({
        modalHeader: header,
        modalBody: body,
        modalStatus: true
      });
    };

and than in button I have:

      <Button onClick={showModal(header="Cards" , body={dataYellowCardsCoop} )}>
        Cards
      </Button>

And in modal i call stateModal.modalStatus, stateModal.modalBody, stateModal.modalStatus .. it is OK ?

Comment: something like that yes, dont use 'setStateModal' i guess -not sure- it will lead problems, use insted  const [modal, setModal]...

Comment: but yes this is the idea, to create the modal depending on the states, and states will be changed for every button click ....

Comment: look, start by creating a static modal wich tack its parameters from the modal state ... then upgrade to the dynamic logic...

Comment: I have created static Modal yet and it working, but doesn´t work with this dynamic way :( React says, that: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: I gave console.log to function show modal and I seems, that I got infinity loop with this function

Comment: can you give me your code so I can check it directly ? you can use https://codesandbox.io/index2 and then share your project's liknk right there...

Comment: Solved .. I had problem with call funtion .. I needed to have () => setStateModal() ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object for all of the states.

```js
const [showConfirmModals, setShowConfirmModals] = useState({
  showConfirmModalGoals: false,
  showConfirmModalBallPos: false,
});

// ...

setShowConfirmModals({
  ...showConfirmModals,
  showConfirmModalGoals: true
})
```